# Chrome Experiencing High Latency and Low Download Speeds

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, latency

In the last week, Chrome (latest version, 24.0.1312.57) on Windows 7 (64 bit) has severely deteriorated in download speeds and latency. Using speedtest.net, Chrome is currently receiving ~2.5mbps down and ~600ms ping times, while Firefox, Safari, IE, and Opera consistently have ~40ms pings and ~12mbps download speeds.

So in an attempt to correct this issue, I've taken these steps:

- I first cleared the entire cache (no effect)
- I then disabled every extension (no effect)
- I uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome (no effect)
- Ran a virus scanner (avast), no threats found

What's strange is that Chrome works fine if it's using an incognito tab. If anyone can help, that'd be great, because I do enjoy using Chrome over Firefox.

Comment: Could it be due to one of your Chrome extensions? As most of those are disabled in incognito tabs.

Comment: As noted, I did try this, though it had no effect :(

Comment: Can you try `chrome.exe --enable-npn-http` or `chrome.exe --enable-npn-http --use-spdy=off` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither had any effect.

Comment: I'm having very high DPC latency suddenly in Chrome as well. When I resize the window my audio stutters!